# How to calculate the sample size for the development of a new clinical test?

Tags: categorical-data, sample-size, continuous-data

How to calculate the appropriate sample size for the development of a new clinical test? The test would either be a quantitative test if the accuracy is good enough (i.e., test would predict a quantitative value similar to blood concentration) or be a semi-quantitative test if not accurate enough for quantitative testing (i.e., indicating statuses such as "healthy", "at risk", "disease"). The accuracy of the test would be evaluated by comparison with a quantitative gold standard.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking how many times to sample from the same person using the same clinical test?  Or are you trying to compare a new clinical test across many patients to an existing test?

Comment: I am trying to compare a new clinical test across many patients to an existing one. Each patient will be tested with the gold standard method and the new clinical test (paired).

Comment: If the outcome of the test is binary (e.g. healthy/disease) I could find enough information in the literature regarding calculations of the sample size. But as far as quantitative data are concerned as well as "semi-quantitative" (more than two groups, like "healthy", "risk", "disease") I did not find any proper information on my own.